# In schema compare, some files erroneously appear as missing in the local DB compared to Azure SQL Server DB. Only a few files are affected, not all

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database, schema, database-schema, azure-repos

In the schema comparison, it shows a list of files that do not exist in the local database when compared to the Azure SQL Server database. In this list, a few files are already present in the local database, but they are incorrectly indicated as not existing in the local database. This discrepancy applies only to few files, not all of them.
Local database : We are using Azure repo so I have clone code from Azure repo (azure devops).
Server DB : Azure SQL Database.
files are table, view, procedure,function

In schema compare setting, Unticked below options.
Application Roles
Broker priorities
Certificate
Database Roles
Permissions
Role Membership
Rules
Security Policies
Signature
Users

I need know what was the issue for this and solution for this issue.